# Impossible to apply text labels to axis

Tags: jquery, charts, jqplot

I'm facing an impasse in properly labeling the following jqPlot chart, which on browser is rendered as this:

[image]

The chart is generated by the following code, here stripped down to the essentials for simplicity:

```
<!-- All scripts and stylesheets included in HEAD -->
/jqplot/src/jquery.min.js
/jqplot/src/jquery.jqplot.min.js
/jqplot/src/jquery.jqplot.css

/jqplot/src/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js
/jqplot/src/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js
/jqplot/src/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js
/jqplot/src/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js
/jqplot/src/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js
```

-

```
<div id='chart_0' style='width: 100%; height: 15em;'></div>
<script id='source' language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
    $.jqplot('chart_0',
      [[[ 0, 1],[ 1, 0],[ 2, 3],[ 3, 2],
        [ 4, 2],[ 5, 2],[ 6, 1],[ 7, 2]
      ]],
    {
      axes: {
        xaxis: {
          min: 0,
          max: 15,
          tickInterval: 1,
          labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
          tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
        },
        yaxis: {
          min: 0,
          max: 5,
          tickInterval: 1,
          labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
          tickOptions: { formatString: "%d" },
        },
      },
      seriesDefaults: {
        renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
          barWidth: 10,
          fillToZero: true,
        }
      }
    });
</script>
```

---

On the horizontal axis the chart labels the numeric sequence `[0, 1, ..., 15]`.
Rather, I wish it to label a set of custom strings, in the form of `["Monday", "Tuesday", "Yesterday", "Today"]`.

I have tried several ways, including modifying the dataset from

```
$.jqplot('chart_0',
  [[ [ 0, 2],[ 1, 5],[ 2, 2],[ 3, 0],
     [ 4, 2],[ 5, 2],[ 6, 1],[ 7, 2] ]],
```

to

```
$.jqplot('chart_0',
  [[ [ "Monday", 2],[ "Yesterday", 5],[ "Today", 2],["etc...", 0] ]],
```

but all what I get is either no vertical bars or no chart at all. 
I'm using jqPlot 1.0.8.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [categoryAxisRenderer](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-categoryAxisRenderer-js.html).  Here's a good [example](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/barTest.html).

Essentially:

```
$.jqplot('chart_0',
  [[[ 0, 1],[ 1, 0],[ 2, 3],[ 3, 2],
    [ 4, 2],[ 5, 2],[ 6, 1],[ 7, 2]
  ]],
{
  axes: {
     xaxis: {
         renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
         ticks: ['Monday','Yesterday','Today', etc...]
     }
 },
```